# Pagination not working in custom post type but perfectly in posts

Tags: pagination

```php
<div class="pagination my-3">
    <?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'show_all'           => false,
        'end_size'           => 1,
        'mid_size'           => 2,
        'prev_next'          => true,
        'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
        'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
        'type'               => 'plain',
        'add_args'           => false,
        'add_fragment'       => '',
        'before_page_number' => '',
        'after_page_number'  => ''
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose this, are you using query_posts get_posts or WP_Query further up the page?

Comment: WP_Query but it works fine in post while  using custom post then does not work

Comment: then there's your problem, you used a new query instead of modifying the main query with `pre_get_posts`. Even if there are more pages, and the pagination shows them, if the main query does not have those pages you will get a 404. It's also very likely you've made a mistake in your `WP_Query` code and that there is no pagination because ti did not find more than one page worth of posts

Comment: Also `$wp_query` is the main query, if you've used `WP_Query` then you're asking it to show the main queries pagination not your custom queries pagination. Use the `pre_get_posts` filter instead and you will be able to use a standard post loop, standard pagination, and you'll get a performance boost